# How to apply css3 animation from current translation?

Tags: css, animation, webkit

I have a box that's currently translated, but when I apply a shake animation to it, it jumps to the upper left side of the screen.

I'd like to shake it from it's current position. How might I do this?

Here's my jsfiddle. Please view in a webkit browser (chrome/safari)

http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/atv7R/

CSS:

```
div {
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(50px, 50px, 0px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(3px); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
}
.shake {
    -webkit-animation-name: shake;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 150ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 20;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('div').addClass('shake')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using move.js

http://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/

they do what I want with the .then() command. One of these days I'm gonna look at the code to see how they do it because it's all done with translates.

Answer (score -1):

You could animate the position with jQuery and then add the add the class with the keyframe animation to get the desired effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/atv7R/3/

```
$('div').animate({
    top: 50,
    left: 50
}, 1000).addClass('shake');
```

or you could acomplish the same thing with css:

http://jsfiddle.net/atv7R/5/

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left:10px;
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(3px, 3px, 0px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    }
}
.shake {
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s, left 1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: shake;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 150ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 20;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Comment: the original question involved using translate as the initial position, not top/left.

Comment: @foreyez I doubt you'll be able to use translate, you would be restating the transform in two places... Tried to give you a viable alternative.